# How to generate a PDF from within the backend in a site that uses Angular?

Tags: angular, pdf, backend

We have a project where we don´t develop the front end, we dont have access to it.

Our team manages backend-service side we need to generates PDFs of the rendered angular pages with little style changes.

In the past the app used to generate both the HTML and the PDFs in the backend, but now that is being breaked into micro-services  we need to achieve this PDF generation without access to the front-end.

Is there any way to do this without access to the angular front-end?
any third party component you can think of to do this task?

Comment: You can create a GET request to the frontend (which is the origin of the request). It should provide you back the html. You can then create a pdf out of this html. It could become complicated, when your frontend requires guards (auth, role etc.) and doesn't let you access the child route

Answer (score 3):

Are you wanting to generate a pdf of the view/page itself? or are you wanting to generate a pdf programmatically FROM angular?

If you want to generate a pdf of the page itself check out https://parall.ax/products/jspdf or https://html2pdf.fr/en/default.

If you want to generate a pdf programmatically from angular check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pdf-make.